# how to say if there is a value over x in a list

Tags: python-3.x

```
# ...

if 'percentageOff' in response.text:
    data = response.json()
    tree = objectpath.Tree(data['products'])
    percent = tuple(tree.execute('$..percentageOff'))
    disc = [percent,ids]
    discounts.append(list(disc))
    print(discounts)
    break

# ...
```

i've tried putting

```
for i in discounts:
    if i < 45.0:
        print("test")
```

but that throws a error saying TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'

the output for the appended list is

```
[[(8.0, 23.0, 25.0), '6889'], [(8.0, 23.0, 29.0, 25.0), '816'], [(8.0, 23.0, 25.0), '863'], [(8.0, 23.0, 25.0), '884'], [(8.0, 23.0), '808']]
```

i want it to be able to find if a value is = or > 45.0 in the output

Comment: Your output contains lists of tuples and strings. Which value do you want to compare with 45?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like?

```
for discount_tuple, item in discounts:
    if any((i > 45.0 for i in discount_tuple)):
        print(f'{item} has discount of 45 or more')
```

I think you got your error because each item in `discounts` is itself a list.

Comment: You can do `any(map((45).__lt__, discount_tuple))` too :)